# e.force:navigateToRelatedList is giving error in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigation, sales-cloud

I am getting the below error while trying to navigate to a related list.

**Error**:

> Unfortunately, the related list you're trying to view isn't in the layout. Please get in touch with your administrator.

But the related list is on the page layout. Can anyone help me please.

```
displayDetails: function(component, event, helper) {
    var ctarget = event.currentTarget;
    var id_str = ctarget.dataset.value;
    id_str=id_str.replace('__c','__r');
    //id_str='cusObject__r';==> related list object name
    alert('id_str-->'+id_str);
    console.log(id_str);
    var relatedListEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToRelatedList");
    relatedListEvent.setParams({
        "relatedListId": id_str,
        "parentRecordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    relatedListEvent.fire();
}
```

[image: Related List]

Comment: what is the actual related list id? are you sure it is correct? try hard-coding it

Comment: I have seen related lists are getting loaded later once the detail page is loaded in lightning. Try finding the related list once the entire page load is completed.